# How to resolve Spacy POS Attribute E1005 Error

Tags: python, error-handling, spacy

I was able to install spaCy and download the standard English model (en_core_web_sm).

But by just loading the standard data model, I received the following error message:

```
import spacy
​
# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser and NER
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


ValueError: [E1005] Unable to set attribute 'POS' in tokenizer exception for '  '. 
Tokenizer exceptions are only allowed to specify ORTH and NORM.
```

I check the `Config.CFG` but don't see any `POS` attribute. Any help is greatly appreciated as I searched the Internet for an answer....

PS, using `pip freeze`, here are some of the libraries

```
spacy==3.0.6
spacy-legacy==3.0.5
en-core-web-sm==2.2.0
```

Comment: That's really weird, you should only get that if you have tokenizer exceptions. Can you provide the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: Updated. Please see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a model for spaCy v2 (the model version starts with 2), but you are using spaCy v3. The models are not compatible with different major versions. You need to uninstall the model and then download the new model:

```
pip uninstall en-core-web-sm
pip -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. You are correct I have a version mismatch. By downgrading `spaCy` to 2.x.x to match the `en-core-web-sm==2.2.0`, it works and runs....thanks again for sharing.

Comment: I am getting the same error while loading the tuned Bert transformer model for NER. These are the installations:
`spacy==3.0.6  
spacy-alignments==0.8.3  
- spacy-legacy==3.0.5  
- spacy-transformers==1.0.2  
en-core-web-trf @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_trf-3.0.0/en_core_web_trf-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Hm, I think that looks ok but it sounds like you still have environment issues. Try installing everything in a clean environment. If that doesn't work, post at this link, with your code, full error output, and the output of `pip freeze`. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/categories/help-installation